# How do you abbreviate "Millions"?

Tags: terminology, abbreviation

M or MM? I prefer "M" -- it's shorter, but someone here was pushing for "MM".

Comment: I don't think that this is on-topic, but I will wait for others to vote to close it.

Comment: Plenty of answers are at http://www.google.com/search?q=abbreviate+millions .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would use M, as it is the SI prefix for million (mega-).

Answer (score 1):

I would use "million", or 10^6, because M stands for molar (concentration in moles per litre) in my discipline.

Comment: I cannot think of any situation in which molar can be confused with "millions". Millions is not generally used by itself, you usually write, for instance, 2M€, 2Mb or 2MΩ. Moreover, you use Molar next to a chemical name, es. CaCl2 0.5M, so there is no ambiguity.

Comment: +1 for scientific notation - the clear, simple and widely used approach.